# C# Swagger: Specify a Fixed Array of Strings as Body Parameters

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger

In a dotnet project i'm trying to list the possible values for a parameter to be able to just select it in dropdown.

but currently the parameter is listed as **object** *(query)* but instead it should be a string type

the code:

`c.OperationFilter<SwaggerExt>();`

```
public class SwaggerExt : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            return;

        foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Name == "P1")
            {
                parameter.Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "object",
                    Properties = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>
                    {
                        {
                            "P1",
                            new OpenApiSchema
                            {
                                Type = "string",
                                Enum = new List<IOpenApiAny>
                                {
                                    new OpenApiString("value-1"),
                                    new OpenApiString("value-2"),
                                    new OpenApiString("value-3")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsz5m.png) of the code, does this resolve the issue?

Comment: thank you @Helen this was part of the solution but it worked only for one value not an array, so i added some properties as mentioned in my answer below, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Helen comment, that was part of the issue,

so what i did to solve this problem is to change the type from an **Object** to an **Array** and then define the list inside the **Items**.

So in order to define an Array of String for a specific parameter in Swagger here is what i did:

I needed also to make the values dynamic from another service: there are multiple ways to achieve this, you can make a constructor and inject only the list or manage it inside the OperationFilter by injecting `IYourService`

```
public class SwaggerCustomsFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    
    public SwaggerCustomsFilter(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            return;

        //
        // Use Linq: firstOrDefault to optimize the foreach loop and check if parameter is not null
        //
        foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Name == "ParameterName")
            {
                var test = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IYourService>();
                var values = test.GetValues();

                parameter.Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "array",
                    Items = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Enum = new List<IOpenApiAny>(values.Select(v => new OpenApiString(v)).ToList())
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

*if your parameter is not an array try what @helen mentioned in the screenshot like this:*

```
if (parameter.Name == "P1")
{
    parameter.Schema = new OpenApiSchema
    {
        Type = "string",
        Enum = new List<IOpenApiAny>
        {
            new OpenApiString("value-1"),
            new OpenApiString("value-2"),
            new OpenApiString("value-3")
        }
    };
}
```